# vue 3 migration proxy set handler returned false

Tags: vuejs3

I have been working on migration from vue 2 to vue 3 and I get an error on the console but I can't figure it out and the error doesn't give detailed explanation. Error like this;

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"id"'
```

Is there anyone that have an idea for this error?

Comment: You should reverse your migration and do step by step again and see which step gives that error

Comment: I guess it is about vue bootstrap package

Answer (score 2):

I know this may not help you now 4mos after the fact but, for me, I received this error when I was accidentally trying to set a `props` value. `props` are read-only so that is why I was receiving the error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with a proxy-wrapped property, where I was unable to modify it directly. Here's an example illustrating the problem and the workaround I found:

```js
console.log(object.prop)  // "Replace me"
object.prop = 'new value' // Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"prop"'
console.log(object.prop)
```

In order to resolve the issue, I did the following:

```js
console.log(object.prop) // "Replace me"
delete object.prop
object.prop = 'new value'
console.log(object.prop) // "new value"
```

I figured out that deleting the property first, and then assigning a new value to it, allowed me to "update" the property. I wanted to share this solution in case others encounter the same problem, as the error message doesn't immediately indicate what's causing it.